# Torricelli's Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A water tank is made by rotating the graph of the function x=g(y) about the y-axis. The volume of the tank at height y is then given by
$V(y) =\pi\int_{0}^{y}g(u)^2 \, du$

A hole is made in the bottom of the tank. According to Torricelli's Law the volume then satisfies
$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} =-k\sqrt{y},$
where y is the height of the water and k is some positive constant.

[image]
Determine the function g(y) when it is given that the change of the height of water per unit time is constant (that is, dy/dt is constant.) and the volume V is 1 when y=1.

This is an old exam, i found the answer, but it does not explain deep. first they uses the chain rule on V(y) and then the toricellis law is used and so on. would really apreciate if someone could explain deeper for my understanding!